# Different validation for different actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the situation. I have a `BlogPost` model wich has a `title`, `content`, `category_name`, `published_at` date, some other fields and some presence validations.
What I want to do is to let the user save a post as a "draft" (withought publishing it). In that case I need to skip most of the validations (pretty much all of them, except for the title and category_name). What is the best `Rails 4` way to do that?

Being more precise:

- Should I leave it one model, or create another model like `DraftPost` and inherit `BlogPost` from it, adding validations?
- Or should I leave it in one model and implement the validations in the controller (what I can think of is validating the `title` and `category_name` manualy on the draft save and saving the model with save!)
- Or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding a `draft` field to the model and validationg with `:if => :draft?` Seems it's the best way to work with it.